# What http status would tomcat returns during redeployment time?

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I am wondering what would be returned by tomcat during redeployment, if the process takes long time.

I need the http status code for apache mod_jk's fail_on_status value.

Comment: You mean hot redeploy, without tomcat restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat will return HTTP 404 while redeploying.

But i suggest to restart Tomcat, because many applications has [ClassLoader leak](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) and after some hot redeploys Tomcat get PermGenSpace exception.